# Design considerations for an RSS client

Tags: c#, rss, rss-reader, websub

I need to develop a RSS client using c# and I wonder how any RSS client stores what the user read or not.
The simple answer is to store all the feeds of each url and mark whether the user read it or not.
So I need to know how other RSS clients manage the feeds state from being read or not from the user. do they store all the feeds from all the urls or not

Also, I need to know if there are any .net Library for client using pubsubhubbub protocol

For example,

If I subscribe for CNN feeds , the application will load the current CNN feeds then I make it read. After while , I open the client , I should find all the feeds that I read is marked as read.

So this means , that the client will store - for example in its database  - all the links of the CNN feeds and save for each link its status whether it is read or not

my question is , is there another way to track the feeds is read or not instead of saving all the feeds of all the sites on DB which will lead to huge database

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow :D

### Representing RSS feeds

You could use the following types to represent feeds and articles :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public abstract class RssItem
{
    public virtual bool IsRead { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class RssFeed : RssItem
{
    public List<RssFeedArticle> Articles { get; set; }

    public override bool IsRead
    {
        get { return Articles.All(s => s.IsRead); }
        set { Articles.ForEach(s => s.IsRead = true); }
    }
}

public class RssFeedArticle : RssItem
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

This is really a simple representation, feel free to enhance it.

Basically when you set `feed.IsRead = true;` all articles will be marked as read, if you query the value it will return `true` only if all the articles have been read.

Example :

```
var article1 = new RssFeedArticle {Name = "article1", Content = "content1"};
var article2 = new RssFeedArticle {Name = "article2", Content = "content2"};
var feed = new RssFeed
{
    Name = "cool feed",
    Articles =
        new List<RssFeedArticle>(new[]
        {
            article1,
            article2
        })
};

article1.IsRead = true;

feed.IsRead = true;
```

### Storing your data

A common approach is to store your application data is in ApplicationData folder or in My Documents.

The advantage of using My Documents is that the user will generally backup this folder, not necessarily the case of ApplicationData for which novice users probably don't even know its existence.

Example for retrieving your application folder :

```
using System.IO;

private void Test()
{
    string applicationFolder = GetApplicationFolder();
}

private static string GetApplicationFolder()
{
    var applicationName = "MyCoolRssReader";
    string folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);

    string applicationFolder = Path.Combine(folderPath, applicationName);
    bool exists = Directory.Exists(applicationFolder);
    if (!exists)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(applicationFolder);
    }

    return applicationFolder;
}
```

If you prefer My Documents instead :

```
string folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

Here's some explanation/advice from a Microsoft developer :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions.aspx

### pubsubhubbub

There's a library for C# : https://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub-publisherclient-csharp/

(from https://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/wiki/PublisherClients)

**If you are satisfied with my answer then do not forget to accept it; if you still have some interrogations update your question and I'll try to address them.**

Comment: I am talking about the RSS web client not windows. so I can't use the my document folder.
I need to know how to track the read urls in any RSS feed
And for the Google link , it is still in progress nothing released

Comment: Edit your questions with all the relevant details.